# C# method give me an extra Console.WriteLine

Tags: c#, methods, console

I have a little problem, in my source code I don't see why is my ToUpload method give me an extra console.writeLine in the Console window. (write out the beer object)

When I call the ToUpload method, and the beer is in the beers dictionary, it give me an extra Console.WriteLine, where write out the beer object at the Console. And I don't know why.

**This is my output:**

- Borsodi sör 160 4.6 1000
- Pilsner Urquell 250 4.4 800
- Soproni Ászok 150, 4.5 900
- Dreher Classic 200, 5.2 600
- 125
- Borsodi sör 160 4.6 475
- Pilsner Urquell 250 4.4 800
- Soproni Ászok 150, 4.5 1350
- Dreher Classic 200, 5.2 600
- Bratista sör, 230, 4.5 300
- Soproni Ászok 150, 4.5 450 // this is extra
- Borsodi sör 160 4.6 100 // and this is

**and i want this:**

- Borsodi sör 160 4.6 1000
- Pilsner Urquell 250 4.4 800
- Soproni Ászok 150, 4.5 900
- Dreher Classic 200, 5.2 600
- 125
- Borsodi sör 160 4.6 475
- Pilsner Urquell 250 4.4 800
- Soproni Ászok 150, 4.5 1350
- Dreher Classic 200, 5.2 600
- Bratista sör, 230, 4.5 300

  ```
  public void ToUpload(Beer beer, int dl)
  {
      int d = 0;
      Beer s = null;
      // search for beer in beers dictionary
      foreach (var item in beers)
      {
          if (item.Key.Equals(beer))
          {
              d = item.Value;
              s = item.Key;
          }
      }
      // if this beer in the beers, update the value
      if (s != null)
      {
          beers[s] = d + dl;
      }
      // if a new beer, just add to beers
      beers.Add(beer, dl); // IDictionary beers = new Dictionary
  }

  public Pub()
  {
      ToUpload(new Beer("Borsodi beer", 160, 4.6), 1000);
      ToUpload(new Beer("Pilsner Urquell", 250, 4.4), 800);
      ToUpload(new Beer("Soproni Ászok", 150, 4.5), 900);
      ToUpload(new Beer("Dreher Classic", 200, 5.2), 600);
  }

  static void Main(String[] args)
  {
      Beer b = new Beer("Borsodi beer", 160, 4.6);
      Beer c = new Beer("Bratista beer", 230, 4.5);
      Beer d = new Beer("Soproni Ászok", 150, 4.5);
      Pub pub = new Pub();
      foreach (var item in pub.beers)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.Key, item.Value);

      }


      Console.WriteLine(pub.Elad("Borsodi beer", 125));


      //pub.ToUpload(b, 2000);
      pub.ToUpload(c, 300); // Don't Write out this beer object
      pub.ToUpload(d, 450); // Write out this beer object the console
      pub.ToUpload(b, 100); // Write out this beer object the console



      foreach (var item in pub.beers)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.Key, item.Value);

      }

      Console.ReadLine();
  ```

Here is the Beer class:

```
public class Beer
{
    string name;
    int price; 
double alcohol;

public string Name { get { return name; } }

public int Price{ get; set; }

public double AlkoholTartalom { get { return alcohol; } }

public Beer(string name, int price, double alcohol)
{
    // ide írja a kódot
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.alcohol = alcohol;
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj is Beer)
    {
        Beer other = (Beer)obj;
        return this.name == other.name;
    }
    return false;
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return this.Name + " " + this.Price+ " " + this.AlkoholTartalom;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing "Else" at the ToUpload method.

```
// if this beer in the beers, update the value
if (s != null)
{
    beers[s] = d + dl;
}
else  // Add this 
    beers.Add(beer, dl); // IDictionary beers = new Dictionary
```

From what i see, this should fix it.
You are adding the beer to dictionary, even thou you should just update it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what type beers is you can just do this:

```
public void ToUpload(Beer beer, int dl)
{
    int d = 0;
    if(beers[beer] != null)
        d = beers[beer];

    beers[beer] = d + dl;
}
```

I know that HashTables will automatically either update or add to the dictionary based on whether or not the key was found when they are accessed this way.